# Find Error in this code.this program is written in PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php 
   echo "Enter Month:";
    $m=trim(fgets(STDIN)); 

    echo "Enter Day:";
    $d=trim(fgets(STDIN));
    //{Write your code here

   if($m>=3 && $m<=6)
   {
       if($d>=20){
           echo"Spring";
       }

   }
   else
   {
       echo"Not Spring";
   }





    //}
    exit;
?>
```

Find error in this code
The duration between March 20 (inclusive) and June 20 (inclusive) is Spring time. Write a program which takes month and day as positive integer input and shows whether its a spring time or not.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like an assignement for class or something, you would gain very little from asking (and not even asking nicely) someone else to do it....

That being said, I'm bored, so i'll guide you a little:

```
if($m>=3 && $m<=6)
{
    if($d>=20){
        echo"Spring";
    }
}
```

This logic is flawed. This will return "Spring" only the days 20 to 31 for the months 3 to 6, which means that something like April 1st (01/04) will not return Spring.

What your if statement should look like is something like `It's the 3rd month and the 20th or later, or it's the 4th month, or it's the 5th month, or it's the 6th month and the 20th or later':

`if(($m == 3 && $d >= 20) || ($m == 4) || ($m == 5) || ($m == 6 && $d <= 20))`

**Extra:**

Judging by your code above, the following might be too advanced, but I want to specify it because handling date as string is overall a bad bad idea and leads to disasters most of the time. If you don't get it, put it aside for now.

The best way to handle it is to threat those as real dates rather than integers using the PHP `DateTime` object:

```
$beginingSpring = Datetime::createFromFormat('m-d', '03-20'); // March 20th.
$endSpring = Datetime::createFromFormat('m-d', '06-20'); // June 20th.
$date = Datetime::createFromFormat('m-d', $m.'-'.d); // Entered date

if($date >= $beginingSpring && $date <= $endSpring){ 
    echo 'Spring'; 
}else{ 
    echo 'Not spring'; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me...I was trying this code many hours.so I post it for solution .this solution also help me in other code of this type.

Comment: Embed | Share
Challenge.phpc

Programmr 
Enter Month:8
Enter Day:2
PHP Warning:  DateTime::createFromFormat(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In c

Comment: The Warning you get is because you did define a value for `date.timezone` in your `php.ini`. If you do not have access to the configuration, you can do `date_default_timezone_set('GMT')` at the beginning of the script. Since you said that the first code works, please mark my answer as resolved.